# Text Editor Rejecting certain words

Tags: 7, nodes, input-formats

I have been having an issue with drupal's text editor. I am making a custom block for FAQ section of my website but whenever I try to html code containing certain words inside

such as 'from' etc. it reload on itself and rejects my code. I know it sounds strange but I have tried everything and narrowed down the issue to this.  for example the text editor reject this code:

```
<p> from </p>
```

but it accepts this code:

```
<p> sample </p>
```

I updated core Drupal, but still this error occurs. Is there any fix for this? ("Full HTML" option is selected) or is there anything wrong with my editor?

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG? CKEditor perhaps?

Comment: Neither. I am using Drupal's default editor.

Comment: Please double-check the "Full HTML" text format's config on [example.com/admin/config/content/formats/full_html](http://example.com/admin/config/content/formats/full_html) and check which filters are activated AND how filter settings are configured.